# Cannot from pandas import Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

### from pandas import Dataframe

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from pandas import Dataframe

ImportError: cannot import name 'Dataframe'

I understand there are workarounds but I need to do this for an assignment. I am using Jupiter Python ver 3.6.

Thsnks in Advance

Comment: Use `DataFrame` instead of `Dataframe`:  `from pandas import DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

`from pandas import DataFrame`

Notice capitalization